# How to multiply a list of vector by list of arrays (by columns) in R

Tags: r

## Given information:

Suppose I have list of two vectors (each with 10 elements). Also, suppose I have a list of arrays (10 arrays for each element of the list). These arrays are lower triangular. That is the upper triangular values are zeros.

## The codes:

The vectors:

```
x <- list(rnorm(10,0,2), rnorm(10,2,2))
```

The arrays:

```
set.seed(47)
a <- vector("list",2)

for( i in seq_along(a)){

a[[i]] <- array(rnorm(5 * 5 * 10), c(5, 5, 10))
for(k in seq(dim(a[[1]])[3])) a[[i]][,,k][upper.tri(a[[i]][,,k], diag = TRUE)] <- 0
```

}

## The needed:

I would like to multiply each element of each vectors by the corresponding elements of the arrays by columns. That is,

1. Multiply the first element of the first vector by the first element of the first elements of the arrays (the first element of arrays list).
2. Then the multiply the second elements of the first vector by the second element of the arrays.
3. Do the same for the second vectors with the second arrays of the arrays list.

That is,

Each vector contains 10 elements and there are 10 values for each arrays. I would like to multiply the first value of the vector by the first values of the arrays and do that for other elements.

## Example:

```
> x
[[1]]
 [1]  1.2062716  1.4671676 -2.9603710 -4.2447263  1.4897441  3.8680305  0.7318295 -3.9691290 -0.8161910
[10]  0.8807681

[[2]]
 [1]  0.80512691 -0.03917115  2.58162187  2.91426812  2.78445280  0.32298579  2.33907433 -0.70444579
 [9] -0.52903520  4.60506480

[[1]]
, , 1

           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000    0
[2,]  0.7111425  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000    0
[3,]  0.1854053  0.01513086  0.00000000  0.00000000    0
[4,] -0.2817650 -0.25204590 -1.82822917  0.00000000    0
[5,]  0.1087755 -1.46575030  0.09147291 -0.04057817    0

, , 2

            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.00000000  0.0000000 0.0000000  0.0000000    0
[2,] -1.60815993  0.0000000 0.0000000  0.0000000    0
[3,] -2.32237229 -1.2004406 0.0000000  0.0000000    0
[4,] -1.96721918  0.8852306 0.5066870  0.0000000    0
[5,]  0.02752681  0.8869350 0.5643018 -0.4876964    0
```

I would like to multiply the first element of the first list by the first element (of the first element of the array list) i.e.,

```
 1.2062716  *  0.7111425
```

and

```
1.2062716  * -1.60815993  

1.4671676 * 0.1854053
```

and

```
1.4671676 * -2.32237229
```

Then the expected multiplication of the first element is

```
> a[[1]][,,1]*x[[1]][1]
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000    0
[2,]  0.8578310  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000    0
[3,]  0.2236491  0.01825193  0.0000000  0.0000000    0
[4,] -0.3398851 -0.30403580 -2.2053409  0.0000000    0
[5,]  0.1312129 -1.76809293  0.1103412 -0.0489483    0
```

The result of the answer is:

```
[[1]]
, , 1

           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000    0
[2,]  0.8578310  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000    0
[3,]  0.2720206  0.02254111  0.00000000  0.00000000    0
[4,]  0.8341290 -0.97492123  7.25647738  0.00000000    0
[5,] -0.4617224 -1.07267929 -0.07465937 -0.03573996    0
```

Do the same thing for the all other elements and for the second element of the list.

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot. I will try. I gave example of what I need. Could you please have a look?

Comment: I posted a solution.  I couldn't reproduce the 'x' value as you didn't use a `set.seed`

Comment: Please check the solution I posted below.  I didn't do a lot of checks

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot. I am sorry but there are a difference.

Comment: Based on the multiplication you showed earlier, `a[[1]][,,1]*x[[1]][1]` is not doing the right way

Comment: @akrun oh. sorry. ok. I will see and then accept the answer. Thanks so, so much.

Comment: I m mentioning about `1.2062716  *  0.7111425`   and `1.2062716  * -1.60815993`  Here the `0.7111425` and `-1.60815993` belong to the 1st and 2nd array

Comment: Do you really wanted the other way?

Comment: @akrun I checked it point by point and yes your answer is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `Map`

```
res <- Map(function(u, v) {
            u[u!=0] <- u[u!=0]*rep(v, dim(u)[3])
            u},
            a, x)
a[[1]][2,1,1]*x[[1]][1]
#[1] 0.3840722
a[[1]][2,1,2]*x[[1]][1]
#[1] -0.8685313

res[[1]][2, 1, 1]
#[1] 0.3840722
res[[1]][2, 1, 2]
#[1] -0.8685313
```

Comment: There were a different. I add it in my question since I could not do that in comment